# The load balancer is not provisioned - BDC Exception in SharePoint 2013

Tags: central-administration, 2013, business-data-catalog

When I click on 'Business Data Connectivity Services' link on 'Manage Service Application' page of Central Administration, I get the following error : "The load balancer is not provisioned. Verify the load balancer was provisioned successfully before retrieving endpoint addresses. " I got a solution from [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/f60259f6-72db-461c-940b-7d81ccf1b50d?prof=required) link, but as per instruction I am unable to install the hotfix for SharePoint 2013. Is there any solution available for this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried deleting the service from central admin, and re-adding it?

Comment: Yes I tried that also, dint work

Comment: @HughWood Can you please post your above comment as answer, I ran into the same issue today with SP2010, and "deleting the service from central admin, and re-adding it worked" for SP2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to your question,

Delete the service from central administration and recreate it.

This will re provision what you require.

Hugh

Comment: I have the same issue but this comes in SharePoint 2016. and re-creation of service is not working in my case.