# When delete BDC Service, the External Content Type and External System are removed too?

Tags: search, external-content-type

I have this problem in my SharePoint 2013 farm, when I use the search feature the system returns this error:

*"The load balancer is not provisioned. Verify the load balancer was provisioned successfully before retrieving endpoint addresses."*

I have read [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50154/the-load-balancer-is-not-provisioned-bdc-exception-in-sharepoint-2013) question and ther'is only one way to resolve the problem:

> Delete the service from central administration and recreate it.

I have two questions:

1. Is there only this solution?
2. If I remove my BDC Service, what happen to my External Content Type and External System? Are they removed too?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about whether that will fix your specific issue, but to answer your question, YES, if you delete the BDC Service Application it will remove your Models, External Systems and External Content Types. Prior to performing the delete you should export all of your Models along with the necesary permissions if necessary.